# Can you extend a tact switch with wiring?

Tags: switches, pins, contact

This might sound like a wierd question but could I, in theory extend a tact switch by soldering wiring to the slots and putting the switch elsewhere.

Basically I ride a motorcycle and have heated grips.
On the temperature controller it has two tact switches on the board, one for temperature up (which has to be held in to turn on) and one for down (which has to be held in to turn off)
I would like to move the tact switches onto the handlebar switch casing as I have a blank space. This is to make it easier to adjust temperature whilst riding.

Or could I wiring in switch with three space on-off-on.

Thank you in advance

I have added picture below, not mine but screenshots. My one is in much better condition 
[image][image][image][image]

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvQAdl.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Yes it is possible to add a momentary [**Toggle switch**](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/e-switch/300AWSP4J2BLKM2RE/300AWSP4J2BLKM2RE-ND/3777912) in parallel. or two high quality waterproof membrane buttons.   Customize toggle to fit & make waterproof. Use 3 of 4 wire phone cable or stranded automotive wire equiv. and prevent vibration of wire on solder joints with PU adhesive or silicone as req'd.

[image]
[image]

[opt 2 not waterproof.](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/c-k/E105MD1ABE/CKN1062-ND/67012)

Making it humidity/rust sealed is hard to do.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, and it is easy since they have already located the switches remotely from the controller.

The circuit has a common between the two switches:

[image]

Looks like the blue wire goes to the + switch, the mauve wire to the - switch and the black wire is common. Just extend the wires and put a switch or switches between them. Center-off momentary toggle is fine as Tony suggests.

The originals are very inexpensive parts (pennies). You can put a much better part in place, for example, if it would fit, the NKK WR series which is IP-67 rated- the wire type ones are better sealed from the back.

[image]